# Migrating django sqlite database to postgresql

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, sqlite

I've been trying for a long while to migrate the sqlite database to a more stable postgresql since I am going into production. I've had some problems, but the one I've hit a roadblock and can't get any further.

To get the backup I ran `./manage.py dumpdata --exclude auth.permission --exclude contenttypes --natural-foreign > db.json` with sqlite configured in *settings.py*.

Once the postgresql database was configured I ran a `./manage.py migrate` with postgresql configured in *settings.py*.

Finally I ran `./manage.py loaddata db.json` and got the following error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: Problem installing fixture '/home/ubuntu/bl/loom/db.json': Could not load web.Project(pk=18): operator does not exist: character varying = integer
LINE 1: ...INNER JOIN "web_project_tags" ON ("web_tag"."tag" = "web_pro...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

The model(s) that the error is referring to has the following code:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='owner')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    img = models.ImageField("Cover", upload_to="img/projects", blank=True, null=True)
    vid = models.URLField("Youtube Link", null=True, blank=True)
    desc = models.TextField("Description", max_length=500)
    stakeholders = models.ManyToManyField(Profile, related_name='stakeholders', blank=True)
    industry = models.ManyToManyField(Industry, related_name="industry")
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name="project_tag")
    is_private = models.BooleanField("Is this a private project?", default=False, help_text="Private projects are not shown on the index.")
    b_type = models.ForeignKey(B_type, help_text="What type of project is this")
    role = models.ForeignKey(Role, related_name="role")
    deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Project"
        verbose_name_plural = "Projects"

class Tag(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField("Tag", max_length=100, primary_key =True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.tag

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Tag"
        verbose_name_plural = "Tags"
```

Update: 
The log file contains a more detailed error and it shows the full query.

```
2016-05-09 00:54:39 UTC ERROR: operator does not exist: 
character varying = integer at character 89 
2016-05-09 00:54:39 UTC HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts. 
2016-05-09 00:54:39 UTC STATEMENT: SELECT "web_tag"."tag" FROM "web_tag" INNER JOIN "web_project_tags" ON ("web_tag"."tag" = "web_project_tags"."tag_id") WHERE "web_project_tags"."project_id" = 18
```

Comment: The error message is telling you that `web_tag.tag` is a string but the corresponding column in `web_project_tags` is an integer, you can't say `varchar_column = integer_column` in PostgreSQL. You have a type problem with your tag relations. Sorry, I don't know enough Python/Django to tell you how to fix it though.

Comment: It doesn't look like your file has been exported in JSON format. Looks like what you have created is an SQL dump. Most unusual because the default format is JSON. Please do extract the line mentioned in the error and add it with the lines on either side of it.

Comment: I did check the dump, and it was exported as json. The file does begin to load, but has the problem @mu-is-too-short is mentioning. I guess there should be a way to cast the columns as the error suggest, I just can't seem to find how.

Comment: Could you post the actual tables that postgresql has created here. and the full error in the image. It's not clear which columns are being joined to. If django doesn't show you the full error you wll find it in the postgresql log (the location will depend on what your operating system is)

Comment: Here's the error from the log: `2016-05-09 00:54:39 UTC ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying = integer at character 89
2016-05-09 00:54:39 UTC HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
2016-05-09 00:54:39 UTC STATEMENT:  SELECT "web_tag"."tag" FROM "web_tag" INNER JOIN "web_project_tags" ON ("web_tag"."tag" = "web_project_tags"."tag_id") WHERE "web_project_tags"."project_id" = 18`

Comment: Are you quite sure that the data dump you have is for the current version of your models? For example if you tried these models in a fresh app, you will find that the Tag models primary key is a varchar and the 'through' table also has a var char. But some where down the line you seem to have had ints for them.

Comment: OK so after tinkering around, I found out just what the verbose was telling me. I do have the latest version of the models, but somehow it doesn't have the right data types. When I run the statement mentioned in the error I get back a string, and I think the postgresql is expecting an integer. This is because I changed the primary key to be true on my model. I guess I need to manually change this column to string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the problem, hopefully this answer will help someone.

After checking the log I checked the postgresql database for the tables it was throwing an error. It turns out that web_project_tags had the wrong data type even though the migrations were done to the latest version. I corrected this data type using:

```
ALTER TABLE problematic_table ALTER COLUMN problematic_column TYPE character varying(100);
```

With this I ended up loading the data with `./manage.py loaddata db.json`and no more errors.